# How to get list of users that have used only one value in multiple rows - MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table for payments. It has a column named user_id, & payment_type. For every payment, a user can have multiple payment types.
I want to find the users that have used only one payment_type in their entire lifetime.

Let me make it clear through an example:
Let's say I have the following data:

```
user_id payment_type
1   UPI
1   NB
2   UPI
2   UPI
```

For the above, I only want `user_id` 2 as the output since for both the payments, it has used only 1 payment_type.

Can someone help?

Comment: You could potentially `GROUP BY user_id, payment_type` if you want just the unique payment types, or you can use that in addition to `SUM` to determine the _number_ of payment types, or many other potential solutions. What are you actually trying to achieve in doing this, being wary of the [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple [HAVING](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-having.aspx) with COUNT should do the trick:

```
select user_id
from my_table
group by user_id
having count(distinct payment_type)=1;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=65f673a7df3ac0ee18c13105a2ec17ad

If you want to include payment_type in the result set , use:

```
select my.user_id,my.payment_type
from my_table my 
inner join ( select user_id
             from my_table
             group by user_id
             having count(distinct payment_type)=1
            ) as t1 on t1.user_id=my.user_id
group by  my.user_id,my.payment_type  ;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=cc4704c9e51d01e4e8fc087702edbe6e